# Python Feedparser - KeyError: 'fullcount'

Tags: python, openwrt, feedparser, arduino-yun

Here is what im asking.  I am using mac osx 10.9, python 2.7.3, feedparser 5.1.3  on arduino yun, i tried to use the following python script to check my gmail and it keeps returning error codes as below.
Here is the full code:

```
root@ArduinoYun:~# vi 1.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import feedparser

USERNAME="mygmail@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="mypsw"
PROTO="https://"
SERVER="mail.google.com"
PATH="/gmail/feed/atom"
print(feedparser.parse(PROTO+USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD+"@"+SERVER+PATH)) 

root@ArduinoYun:~# ./1.py
{'feed': {}, 'bozo': 1, 'bozo_exception': URLError('unknown url type: https',), 'entries': []}
```

After installing openssl pkg, problem above solved, yet there's a new one...
Code as below:

```
...
pprint.pprint(feedparser.parse(PROTO+USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD+"@"+SERVER+PATH)["feed"])

root@ArduinoYun:~# ./1.py
{'fullcount': u'0',
 'link': u'http://mail.google.com/mail',
 'links': [{'href': u'http://mail.google.com/mail',
            'rel': u'alternate',
            'type': u'text/html'}],
 'subtitle': u'New messages in your Gmail Inbox',
 'subtitle_detail': {'base': u'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom',
                     'language': None,
                     'type': u'text/plain',
                     'value': u'New messages in your Gmail Inbox'},
 'title': u'Gmail - Inbox for USERNAME@gmail.com',
 'title_detail': {'base': u'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom',
                  'language': None,
                  'type': u'text/plain',
                  'value': u'Gmail - Inbox for USERNAME@gmail.com'},
 'updated': u'2014-07-22T21:08:57Z',
 'updated_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=21, tm_min=8,    
tm_sec=57, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=203, tm_isdst=0)}
```

It seems everything is alright. But when the script got modified as below:

```
...
newmail = int(feedparser.parse(PROTO+USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD+"@"+SERVER+PATH)["feed"]  
["fullcount"])
root@ArduinoYun:~# ./1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./1.py", line 10, in <module>
 newmail = int(feedparser.parse(PROTO+USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD+"@"+SERVER+PATH)["feed"]   
["fullcount"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/feedparser-5.1.3-py2.7.egg/feedparser.py", line 375,   
in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'fullcount'
```

Comment: What does this report: `feedparser.parse('https://www.eff.org/rss/updates.xml')`?

Comment: Additionally, perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830333/arduino-due-https-support) is related. Does the python on your arduino have https support in general?

Comment: u r right, after using opkg install python-openssl and run the script again, no more URLError then. Thx very much. But there's another problem...