# Unable to send POST request from Arduino to Google Form

Tags: arduino, google-docs, http-post

I'm using WiFi CC3000 shield and Adafruit_CC3000.h library. I'm able to connect to my wifi network and all examples work. But my sketch doesn't :(
Here is my `loop()` function:

```
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("In-loop");
  unsigned long ip;
  cc3000.getHostByName("docs.google.com", &ip);
  client = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 80);
  if (client.connected())
  {
    Serial.println("Connected!!!");

    String data = "entry.1820200471=46";
    data += "&submit=Submit";

    client.println(F("POST docs.google.com/forms/d/1YABi7F1ViEqVknN74dQhNLLJqq0RJLRr1QjohRk0qhc/formResponse"));
    // client.println(F("HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
    client.println(F("Host: docs.google.com\r\n"));
    client.println(F("Accept: */*\r\n"));
    client.println(F("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"));
    client.println(F("User-Agent: runscope/0.1\r\n"));
    client.println(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"));
    client.println(F("Connection: close\r\n"));
    client.print(F("Content-Length: \r\n"));
    client.println(data.length());
    client.println();
    client.print(data);
    client.println();

    Serial.println("POST docs.google.com/forms/d/1YABi7F1ViEqVknN74dQhNLLJqq0RJLRr1QjohRk0qhc/formResponse");
    // Serial.println("HTTP/1.1");
    Serial.println("Host: docs.google.com");
    Serial.println("Accept: */*");
    Serial.println("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
    Serial.println("User-Agent: runscope/0.1");
    Serial.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    Serial.println("Connection: close");
    Serial.print("Content-Length: ");
    Serial.println(data.length());
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(data);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("----------");
    unsigned long lastRead = millis();
    while(client.connected() && (millis() - lastRead < 3000)) {
      while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.print(c);
        lastRead = millis();
      }
    }
    Serial.println("----------");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not connected");
  }
  delay(15000L);
}
```

And the output I get is follow:

```
In-loop
Connected!!!
POST docs.google.com/forms/d/1YABi7F1ViEqVknN74dQhNLLJqq0RJLRr1QjohRk0qhc/formResponse
Host: docs.google.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: runscope/0.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close
Content-Length: 33

entry.1820200471=46&submit=Submit
----------
----------
```

I've tried my request [here](http://www.hurl.it/) and it works (actually some headers I took from there).

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this various times but I have not found a good way to use POST directly. I have read that it is because google requires https for all communication.

To make it work a relay service like pushinhbox.com is required.

Here is a good guide:
http://m.instructables.com/id/Post-to-Google-Docs-with-Arduino/

Arduino can't because it doesn't have the programming space or the ram to run SSL easily or in a usable way. Here is a good quick discussion about it:
[Arduino Due HTTPS Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830333/arduino-due-https-support)

You could us another platform like the Intel Galileo which is a Linux board that runs arduino code
http://arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileo

Or another like raspberry pi or beaglebone black.